# Facebook API App Access Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been using for many years my `FACEBOOK_APP_ID|FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET` as an app access token for accessing the facebook API, but lately it seems to be giving me not up to date data.

For example, on this page:

https://www.facebook.com/pg/Vallagruppen/posts

If I just view in the graph explorer with the default access tokens, I get the correct results:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=Vallagruppen%2Fposts&version=v2.11

But if I change the access token in the explorer to one like above, with an `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` I am suddenly not getting all the posts, the newest few are not showing up.

Additionally it will say: "Access Token Info Warning Failed to debug token"

Any idea why?

Comment: try with a page token, there has been some changes according to the changelog

Comment: Maybe those posts target a specific audience - in such a case, you can not get them with your app token, you would need to use a user access token for someone who can see the posts on Facebook, or a page access token for the page.

Comment: @luschn if you can submit as an answer with some more detail I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: it´s not really an answer so far, just some idea to test